# Virtual host doesn't read .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, virtualhost

I just created virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost myvirtualhost:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@myvirtualhost
ServerName myvirtualhost

DocumentRoot /home/myname/sites/public_html

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>


<Directory /home/myname/sites/public_html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

It works, but  it cant read .htacces file in public_html:

```
DirectoryIndex otherindex.php
```

I tried change all AllowOverride to All, but I get 500 error. How can I fix this ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is mod_dir activated ?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

You also need to be broader in your allowoverride directive, you should at least put "AllowOverride Indexes"

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: yes my mod_dir is active, I tried with only `indexes` , and everthing I do with AllowOverride, I always get `Internal Server error`

Comment: What is your error.log saying about these internal server errors ?